# basic hasClass jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function buttons(simon, j){
    $(".simon-button").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).hasClass(".simon-button"));
    });
}
```

Really what to me seemed rather basic, that when a class that has the simon-button class was clicked I wanted it to do some stuff. When I checked the console.log this was returning false? I find this fascinating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the . in `hasClass` function. That's why it's returning false. Your class name is "simon-button" not ".simon-button". ".simon-button" is a selector.

Comment: that worked perfectly! I should have read the documentation more carefully! I'll mark you as correct when I can